# Application Launch Bar (ALB) icons do not work

Tags: lxde

I accidentally deleted the ALB icons by right clicking an icon and hit remove (went too quick to tell which item I actually hit).  Bottom line:  all my icons were gone.  I looked up the process to add items to the ALB and put all the icons back on the bar.  However, nothing happens when I click on the icons.  I have done this three time with the same result.

Norm

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to delete the Application Launch Bar and create a new one.  The only thing that is different is the icon for the Application menu  -- cannot get Raspberry Pi symbol.

Norm